# Memcached pool not working as expected

Tags: php, memcached, silex

So I have two Memcached servers.
In my PHP I have created a Memcached service which use `addServer` for managing the servers.

```
$app['memcached'] = $app->share(
    function ($app) {
        $memcached = new \Memcached;
        $memcached->setOption(
            \Memcached::OPT_PREFIX_KEY,
            $app['memcached.config']['prefix']
        );

        foreach ($app['memcached.config']['servers'] as $server) {
            $host = $server['hostname'];
            $port = isset($server['port']) ? $server['port'] : 11211;

            $memcached->addServer($host, $port);
        }

        return $memcached;
    }
);
```

I then create a status page where I try to do a simple set and get key to verify things are working as expected.

```
    $time = time();

    $memcached->set('system_check', $time);

    $memcached_status = $memcached->get('system_check') == $time
        ? StatusInterface::STATUS_OK
        : StatusInterface::STATUS_ERROR;
```

This gives me OK half of the time when refreshing and half of the time ERROR.

I then output getServerList and getStats to see more information on whats going on.

This is what I get.

Memcached clearly have the two servers registered. (the server ip's is obscured by x's)

```
xx.xx.xx.xx 11211
xx.xx.xx.xx 11211
```

The stats gives me this half of the time:

Server 1:

```
pid 6027
uptime 4486
threads 4
time 1441804532
pointer_size 64
rusage_user_seconds 0
rusage_user_microseconds 84005
rusage_system_seconds 0
rusage_system_microseconds 76004
curr_items 4
total_items 122
limit_maxbytes 67108864
curr_connections 5
total_connections 156
connection_structures 6
bytes 2286
cmd_get 123
cmd_set 122
get_hits 118
get_misses 5
evictions 0
bytes_read 126989
bytes_written 145298
version 1.4.13
```

Server 2:

```
pid -1
uptime 0
threads 0
time 0
pointer_size 0
rusage_user_seconds 0
rusage_user_microseconds 0
rusage_system_seconds 0
rusage_system_microseconds 0
curr_items 0
total_items 0
limit_maxbytes 0
curr_connections 0
total_connections 0
connection_structures 0
bytes 0
cmd_get 0
cmd_set 0
get_hits 0
get_misses 0
evictions 0
bytes_read 0
bytes_written 0
version
```

and the other half I get this:

Server 1:

```
pid -1
uptime 0
threads 0
time 0
pointer_size 0
rusage_user_seconds 0
rusage_user_microseconds 0
rusage_system_seconds 0
rusage_system_microseconds 0
curr_items 0
total_items 0
limit_maxbytes 0
curr_connections 0
total_connections 0
connection_structures 0
bytes 0
cmd_get 0
cmd_set 0
get_hits 0
get_misses 0
evictions 0
bytes_read 0
bytes_written 0
version
```

Server 2:

```
pid 5201
uptime 5552
threads 4
time 1441805639
pointer_size 64
rusage_user_seconds 0
rusage_user_microseconds 132008
rusage_system_seconds 0
rusage_system_microseconds 60003
curr_items 3
total_items 121
limit_maxbytes 67108864
curr_connections 5
total_connections 95
connection_structures 7
bytes 566
cmd_get 124
cmd_set 121
get_hits 120
get_misses 4
evictions 0
bytes_read 18306
bytes_written 52682
version 1.4.13
```

So its like its only using one of the servers at a time... this makes sense if its a pool and it handles this internally. Fine.. but its trying to get the key 'system_check' from server 1 and server 2 at different times. This makes no sense to me. It should know where the entry is placed.

Did I setup the Memcached servers in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

When further debugging the Memcached servers they responded with error code **47** (**MEMCACHED_SERVER_TEMPORARILY_DISABLED**).

The hosting company had a bad iptables configuration that didn't allow the two memcached servers to communicate with each other. When this was fixed everything started working as expected.